# VBA solution for moving pivot table filter range for week numbers

Tags: excel, vba

If it is possible please can someone provide the code that will enable me to automate the process of changing filters for week numbers on numerous pivot tables.

I produce a weekly report that requires a 10 week period range. Therefore, every week I have to remove from numerous pivot tables the Week filter that has become the 11th week and add to the Week filter the previous week.

I have provided a recorded macro version of the process and a screen shot of the table to help explain. I've tried various searches but I cannot find anything relevant. Any help that can be provided I will greatly appreciate.

[Image of pivot table before filter is updated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSLfo.png)

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'
'
Range("B15").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TopPvt").PivotCache.Refresh
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TopPvt").PivotFields("Week")
    .PivotItems("45").Visible = False
    .PivotItems("3").Visible = True
End With
Range("B21").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is the solution to my question. Thanks to Taccoo73 and a bit of tweaking on my part I was able to get the code to work how I needed it to.

The week numbers, e.g. 47 to 4 need to be put in specified cells. So, 47 needs to be put in "c4", 52 in "d4", 1 to be put in "e4", 4 to be put in "f4".

```
Sub test150()

Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem
Dim begin As Integer
Dim finish As Integer
Dim begintwo As Integer
Dim finishtwo As Integer


On Error GoTo Err
begin = Range("c4")
finish = Range("d4")
begintwo = Range("e4")
finishtwo = Range("f4")


For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables


Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Week")


    pf.EnableMultiplePageItems = True

For Each pi In pf.PivotItems

    pi.Visible = pi >= begin And pi <= finish Or pi >= begintwo And pi <= finishtwo

Next pi
Next pt


Err:
Resume Next

MsgBox "Finished"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub Test2()

Dim firstdate As Integer, seconddate As Integer

seconddate = Format(Date, "ww") - 1
firstdate = Format(Date - 84, "ww") - 1

Range("B15").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TopPvt").PivotCache.Refresh
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("TopPvt").PivotFields("Week")
    .PivotItems(firstdate).Visible = False
    .PivotItems(seconddate).Visible = True
End With
Range("B21").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I gave it a try but I get an error. It goes to B15 but then I get an Error '400' if run via the macro, or I get an 'Runtime Error 1004' if I run it via Visual Basic. Do you know what the cause of the errors may be? I've tried to find the cause but I cannot find any thing.

Thanks for your time and help dwirony, I appreciate it. Even if there is no solution this is helping me to learn VBA. :)

Comment: You need to make sure your 'ActiveSheet' is the one with the pivot table on it- otherwise you need to explicitly refer to your sheet

Comment: When run I'm in active sheet, I've also run same code from a brand new workbook but the same errors occur. I've tested further and it's the -84 part that triggers the errors. But when -84 is taken out only the refresh part of code runs. Thanks for your help though  :)